# Problems using SVN with VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, svn

I've been reading about how SVN works with Visual Studio. I'm using VS 2008 and worried about possible problems of using SVN with VS 2008.

Can anyone share their experience with SVN + VS 2008?

Thanks heaps!

Note: I realized throwing GIT into the mix kinda diluted the real question I wanted to ask. So, I've restricted the question to just SVN + VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good IDE-VC integration is most important when your IDE supports refactoring-operations which include renaming files. Using Eclipse JDT without Subversion-integration would be hopelessly inefficient since a renamed class would reappear after an "svn update" unless Eclipse informed Subversion that the file has been removed.

If you aren't doing any such "filesystem-altering" refactorings, VC-integration in your IDE is not terribly important, and you can do fine with for example TortoiseSVN.

Comment: I agree. Having seen how Eclipse + subclipse works with SVN, I think proper IDE integration is important to exploit the full capabilities of SVN. Thanks Jesper for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to need a plugin to interface Visual Studio 2008 with svn.  [Ankh](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) seems to be pretty popular and I've heard of [Visual SVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Personally I don't get too excited about IDE integration; I use TortoiseSVN in explorer, which IMO works just as well, without adding more weight to VS. AnkhSVN, Visual SVN and SlickEdit Versioning Toolbox are among the integrated tools.

But from what I understand (from dialogue only), Git != SVN...

Comment: The visual stuff in Visual Studio helps me remember when I added things :o

Comment: TortoiseSVN tells you in explorer - it whacks a big question mark on the file/folder to say "did you mean to add this", and it shows it on screen when you do a commit. Makes it hard to miss.

Comment: I'm with Marc. I actually prefer managing my version control through TortoiseSVN rather than an IDE plugin. It's much cleaner and gives me greater control over what goes into source control (I don't have to add something to my solution to store it in SVN, only the folder where everything is stored).

Comment: Yes, git definitely does not equal svn in any way.  git is a distributed version control system, while svn is a centralized replacement for cvs.  Linus Torvalds can explain in greater detail and vehemence (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XpnKHJAok8).

Comment: Yes Marc, I know it shows it in Explorer, but it is no nearly as convenient as seeing an indicator in Visual Studio.

Comment: @Gromer - having used both approaches for extended periods of time, I disagree. But that's OK; we're allowed to disagree.

Comment: @Marc Gravell  No, we are not allowed to disagree!  But in all seriousness, I think I need/like it because I will totally forget to add new items to SVN if I don't see it in VS.  I always forget to go into the folder, but I am getting better.  But back to the original post, I've not seen issues with SVN + VS2008 ever, it's what I use on all my out of work projects.

Comment: Don't forget about the obj/bin/Debug/Release directories. You'll also need to ignore *.sou files as well. Tortoise doesn't seem to get it right all the time for me.

Answer (score 2):

The [Agent SVN](http://zeusedit.com/agent/) is MS-SCCI plug-in that works with *Visual Studio* and because it is MS-SCCI, it integrates directly with the source control menus found in *Visual Studio* itself.

Answer (score 1):

I've used SVN both with and without IDE plugins in VS 2008 and have seen no issues.

Answer (score 1):

TortoiseSVN is really good, but VisualSVN is fantastic if you're using VS 2008.  Git is terrible for VS developers (or for running on Windows generally).

Answer (score 1):

You have several options for SVN + VS2008.

1) Use TortoiseSVN without integrating with VS2008. This is what I use most of the time and there's no issue. (If you don't mind leaving the IDE once in a while)

2) Use TortoiseSVN and integrate it with VS2008 yourself by mapping your custom toolbar buttons to TortoiseSVN automation commands. [See this blog](http://blog.vorpal.cc/category/development/tortoisesvn-in-visual-studio.html)

3) Use VisualSVN (These guys fully integrate TortoiseSVN into VS2008 for you!)

4) Use AnknSVN (free and open source, but its not based on TortoiseSVN)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to see much bigger differences due to the different paradigms of svn and git than you will through anything related to Visual Studio integration.

Explaining these differences is a bit of a job, and either one will make your life happier in various ways, so I wouldn't worry about which one you use. You can always change later, and you won't truly understand the differences until you've used both, anyway, if you decide to go that route.